# Using a broadcast receiver to sync data between activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it a good way to use a broadcast receiver for syncing multiple data between activities.

**My Scenario:**
I have DisplayActivity and CreateEditActivity.

On my DisplayActivity I have created a broadcast receiver 
that will listen to changes on my CreateEditActivity, also 
this activity contain a list of data. Then when I open 
CreateEditActivity all the present data in DisplayActivity
 will be passed to the CreateEditActivity, on the CreateEditActivity I can create new data item and if the creation is successful I can pass this item thru broadcast. I know that this would be easier using just fragment and listener also using startActivityForResult does not fit on this process for me., But can I implement this process using broadcast receiver to pass sync data between activities. Hoping for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea.

Only one Activity is at the top of the stack at a given time. You should not make the assumption that your other Activity is alive. The system could have killed it. (You can test this by enabling the developer's option "Don't keep activities".)

It would be better to use persistent storage (Room, SharedPreferences or so). You could also try ViewModels(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to avoid the burden of handling lifecycle events.

If you don't want persistence and your data can implement Parcelable just pass them to the other activity through Bundle.